# Read resource inside context (.war) from a jar file

Tags: servlets, jar, servletcontextlistener, war

I am using JBoss4.0.1 and Struts2.1.6

I have an application which have some configuration file(appConfig.xml in folder WEB-INF/config).
This configuration file contains the relative paths of other files to be read.(other.xml, some.xml etc). Application is deployed as .war inside default/deploy

I have a Utility package that reads the configuration files. I have deployed the utility.jar inside default/lib

In c`ontextInitialized` method of `ServletContextListener` I am reading the `appConfig.xml` and passing `IOStream` on `appConfig` to my Utility Class, which reads this file and loads all the context relative paths.

How can I read these files now? Because if I try to create an input stream it is returned NULL.

I have tried following inside Utility Class.

**read method is called from inside the contextInitialized method of ServletContextListener**

```
public void read(){ 
this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/some.xml");
}

public void read(ClassLoader cl){ 
  cl.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/some.xml"); --> Null
  cl.getResourceAsStream("/../config/some.xml"); --> Null
  cl.getResourceAsStream("../config/some.xml"); --> Null
}

public void read(ServletContext ct){ 
 ct.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/some.xml");.
 ct.getResourceAsStream("/../config/some.xml"); --> Null
 ct.getResourceAsStream("../config/some.xml"); --> Null
}
```

Comment: I have tried to similar question in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585553/how-to-load-resource-from-jar-file-packaged-in-a-war-file/16082211#16082211). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of following would work because /WEB-INF/config is not in classpath so classloader doesn't know anything about it,

```
public void read(){ 
this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/some.xml");
}

public void read(ClassLoader cl){ 
  cl.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/some.xml"); --> Null
  cl.getResourceAsStream("/../config/some.xml"); --> Null
  cl.getResourceAsStream("../config/some.xml"); --> Null
}
```

Those 2 doesn't work because it goes out of the context (.. can't be first element),

```
public void read(ServletContext ct){ 

 ct.getResourceAsStream("/../config/some.xml"); --> Null
 ct.getResourceAsStream("../config/some.xml"); --> Null
}
```

I don't quite understand your intention. If you know the file is in "/WEB-INF/config/some.xml", why do you want read it from "/../config/some.xml"?

It's not a good idea to store configuration file inside war. You should consider moving it somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for your comments, Just want to add a couple fo things for your understanding.

1. WEB-INF/config is in added in class path
2. this is one time configuration so i need it inside the .war.
3. there can be multiuple application context to have the same  configuration so i created one utility package which reads this kind of configuration. 

Now from within the context i want the utility to read my configuration file.

i hope this will better help you understand the problem
your help is appreciated.