# Add resource file to artifact in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, resources, intellij-idea

I'm creating a plugin to de reflected and call by main application. This plugin uses xml file and I want to make it embedded resource. I build plugin as artifact (JAR). My actions:

1) Put xml file to directory 'trunk/res' configured as `'source root'`;

2) Performed `'make module'` action for the module in which directory 'trunk/res' is;

3) Into the plugin I access xml file through file path `dom = db.parse("trunk//res//resource.xml");`

But when I call plugin from the main application I get this exception about system cannot find the file `'MainApp/trunk/trunk/res/resource.xml'`.
I guess I don't extract resource properly, but how to do it correctly?

Comment: So `resource.xml` is located in jar?

Comment: If `trunk/res` is a root, why do you specify it in the path? How does `db.parse` load the resource? Why double slashes?

Comment: Yes, Artifacts|Output Layout shows that jar contains `resource.xml (...\PlugnProject\trunk\res)`

Comment: @Zharro can you unzip your jar and check if `resource.xml` is really inside it and show structure of the jar file.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov It is. Jar contains file: `JarContent\res\resource.xml`

Comment: `dom = db.parse("trunk//res//resource.xml")` where does this code called? From the main application or from plugin?

Comment: From plugin.Should I load resourse file in a different way?

Comment: @Zharro yes, you need to load file using `getResourceAsStream` method. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585553/how-to-load-resource-from-jar-file-packaged-in-a-war-file

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov thanx, but what to pass to getResourceAsStream()? I tried `InputStream xmlFileStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("res\\AIP_82.xml")`, but xmlFileStream  == null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

And see if you're really calling from jar.
And then

```
InputStream xmlFileStream = getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("res\\AIP_82.xml")
```