# JBoss AS 6.0.1 class resourcestream

Tags: classloader, jboss6.x, jboss-4.2.x

I am trying to migrate application from Jboss 4.2.3 to Jboss 6.0.1.in our application i have to access a resource (image) from war folder.

> ```
> WAR
>
> |__ logo.jpg
>
> |__images/icons
>
> |__WEB_INF
>
>      |__classes
>
>      |__jps
>
>      |__logo.jpg
> ```

I would like to access logo.jpg. in JBoss 4.2.3 this.getClassLoader().getResource("logo.jpg")      --> will return path/handle of logo.jpg in war folder

but in Jboss 6.0.1, same code returns null & i am not able to access any resource in war folder.

Please help me how to access logo.jpg in war folder & logo.jpg in WEB_INF folder dynamically in JBoss6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong classloader as explained here:

[How to load resource from jar file packaged in a war file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585553)

Using `this.getClassLoader()` will only be able to access resources under `WEB-INF/classes`.
Also you should use `getResourceAsStream()`.